# Which files to keep under source control for google-chrome-app?

Tags: google-chrome-app

https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/mobile-chrome-apps allows Chrome Apps to work on mobile.

Their getting started wiki is really good to get things working but it generates a lot of files with absolute paths. Nothing is said about which files to keep under source control.

At the moment I'm using each build: `$ cca create YourApp --link-to=path/to/manifest.json` which seems just wrong (for example the `config.xml` is lost).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TLDR; `www/` is by far the most important.  For the rest, just control what you edit, and trust that `cca create --link-to=` will re-create the project in a good state.

---

The files generated during `cca create` fall into two main buckets:

1. Your application;  This obviously includes everything in the `www/` folder, but also `config.xml`, `merges/` (optional), and `hooks/` (optional).
2. `cordova`/`cca` build artifacts;  This includes `plaforms/` and `plugins/`, and, well, anything else :)

Absolutely you should version control #1.  Many developers don't actually use `merges/` or `hooks/` (at least at first), and `config.xml` is actually auto-generated during `cca create` using values from your `www/manifest.json`, so its fine to not version it unless you made manual edits.  We realize its common to add `<preference>`'s there, so we are [working on adding support for importing `merges/` `hooks/` and `config.xml` using `--link-to=path/to/config.xml`](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-5833).  Sorry if you need this feature today, please follow [this issue](https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/mobile-chrome-apps/issues/105) to find out when it is resolves in `cca`.

As for #2, that depends on your preference.  If you are making edits directly to the native bits of the platforms, then you should absolutely add those to version control.  Or, if you want 100% control over how those bits evolve and you are 100% happy with the way the projects are working for you today, then sure, add them to version control.

However, we (`cca` and `cordova` developers) are constantly fixing, evolving, and improving `platforms/` and `plugins/`, and by far the easiest way to "upgrade" your project right now is to just re-create it.  We try very hard to be backwards compatible (and yell loud when we aren't), so you should have considerable confidence that a project today will work at least as well created next week.

Personally, I keep only #1 in version control, and re-create projects often (whenever the tools update, hey its quick!).  Its not been an issue yet.  I think the `cca create --link-to=path-to-app` syntax really helps here, and we are considering adding support for a `cca update` to make this even easier, eventually.

Finally, one developer working with `cca` has [blogged about his experience](http://nothingbutsnark.svbtle.com/using-chrome-mobile-apps-to-make-oplop-an-androidios-app), and one of the topics he covers is what to check in.  He came to the same conclusion as we suggest.

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks that's what I started to use (keeping only `www`). I agree with you something like `cca update` or relative paths would be good when keeping all files is required. Another issue is that the project structure looks a bit reversed to me. See also [my reported issue](https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/mobile-chrome-apps/issues/107). Should the hidden folders (`.*`) also be under source control if you keep (1) and (2)?

Comment: Which hidden folders?  Cordova has 1 hidden folder `.cordova/` but its optional and we do not use it by default (haven't for a while now).

Comment: Examples: `./platforms/android/.project`, `./platforms/android/.staging` or the file `./plugins/org.apache.cordova.statusbar/.fetch.json`.

Comment: If you are planning to version `platforms/` and `plugins/` I would version everything.  That said, `.staging` is being removed entirely right now.  If you re-create your project in a few weeks you should not have one any more.  Yet another reason to consider not versioning those folders.