# Mobile Chrome App .gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore, google-chrome-app

While developing a Mobile Chrome App, which files should I include in .gitignore? Maybe both build directories for Android and iOS platforms?

I know that I shouldn't include binaries in git, but I don't know which files in the build folder I can ignore.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, theres another SO question for this: [Which files to keep under source control for google-chrome-app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22126126/which-files-to-keep-under-source-control-for-google-chrome-app)

And we have an open github issue to figure this out and provide guidance:  https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/mobile-chrome-apps/issues/85

And we have some existing users of `cca` who have already devised their own `.gitignore`: https://github.com/plaxdan/react-topcoat-demo

The truth is, the answer isn't set in stone, and will likely change in the future.  We are trying to help you figure out the answer for yourself, and are hoping to get feedback about what worked best for you.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have an entry specifically for multi-platform projects, but you might be able to combine the android entry with others from [this collection of useful gitignore templates](https://github.com/github/gitignore)